# SQL order by duplicate rows descending

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, sql-order-by

The table I have looks like:

```
cust_ref | account_num  
123456  |     001132  
321234   | 123213  
325123 | 412312  
123456 | 312321
```

What I'm basically trying to do is sort the duplicate cust_ref rows together and order it so that all duplicates are in a descending order from row 1 down. i.e if there's a cust_ref number that corresponds to 3 account_num's then it will be in a higher row over a cust_ref that corresponds to 2 account_num's

e.g

```
cust_ref | account_num  
123456  |     001132  
123456 | 312321   
321234   | 123213  
325123 | 412312
```

my current query is:

```
select cust_ref,  
       account_num  
from (
  select cust_ref,  
         account_num,  
         max(phone_num)  
   from table_name  
   group by cust_ref,  account_num
)
```

Comment: What is your RDBMS? Oracle, MSSQL, mysql, PostgreSql...? Please add tag of your RDBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your RDBMS support `window functions (analytic functions)` then you could use this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_ref) AS cnt,
    cust_ref, account_num, 
    MAX(phone_num) AS max_phone_num
FROM table_name
GROUP BY cust_ref, account_num
ORDER BY 1 DESC, 2, 3;    --cnt DESC, cust_ref, account_num
```

Tested in [rextester for Oracle](https://rextester.com/GDW93700)

If you want to order in each group of `cust_ref, account_num` too, then use this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_ref) AS cnt,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt_in_group,
    cust_ref, account_num, 
    MAX(phone_num) AS max_phone_num
FROM table_name
GROUP BY cust_ref, account_num
ORDER BY cnt DESC, cnt_in_group DESC, cust_ref, account_num;
```

Link [rextester](https://rextester.com/RUOX72562)

Comment: Apologies, first time posting. This looks like exactly what I needed, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Pham's answer is better then this, **but**, if you wanted to do it old-school, something like this should work

```
declare  @cust_accts table 
( 
   cust_ref  int NOT NULL, 
   account_num int not null
)

insert into @cust_accts values (123456 , 001132)
insert into @cust_accts values (321234 , 123213)
insert into @cust_accts values (325123 , 412312)
insert into @cust_accts values (123456 , 312321)

select a.cust_ref, 
       a.account_num,
       b.acct_cnt
from   @cust_accts  a
join   
(
    select cust_ref, count(*) as acct_cnt
    from   @cust_accts
    group  by cust_ref
) b
on a.cust_ref = b.cust_ref
order by b.acct_cnt, a.cust_ref, a.account_num
```

Not sure why my answer show's above Pham's, his is much more elegant.

Comment: This idea is nice when your DBMS don't support `window/ analytic functions`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select cust_ref, account_num
from t
order by count(*) over (partition by cust_ref) desc,
         cust_ref,
         account_num;
```

You can include the count in the desired results as well, but your sample results only include the two specified columns.

If your database does not support window functions, you can also use a subquery there.